# How to watch changes on another module?

Tags: webpack

In my webpack configuration, I have [multiple `resolve.root`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) to treat each assets folders as an independent module. Because I am developing my assets as separate modules, I wanted to watch the changes done in them.

Sample `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path')
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    root: [
      './proj1/assets/',
      './proj2/assets/',
    ],
  },
  entry: {
    'app1': './proj1/assets/app1'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/proj1'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  }
})
```

Let `awesomeapp` export a `AwesomeComponent` and can be resolved from `proj2/assets`.

```
// File: proj1/assets/app1.js
import { AwesomeComponent } from 'awesomeapp'
// ^The above import will not watch changes in `AwesomeComponent`

// BUT with relative import, webpack will watch it.
import { AwesomeComponent } from '../../proj2/assets/awesomeapp'
// ^The above import will watch changes in `AwesomeCompoent`
```

How to `webpack --watch` changes made in such import?

---

> Mentioned in the Tutorial:
>   https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#watch-mode
>
> > When using watch mode, webpack installs file watchers to all files, which were used in the compilation process. If any change is detected, it’ll run the compilation again. When caching is enabled, webpack keeps each module in memory and will reuse it if it isn’t changed.

Comment: Perhaps I could look at how to add the file watcher manually.... Thus tracking all those files...

Answer (score 0):

`resolve.root` needs an absolute path, NOT relative path. So,

```
resolve: {
  root: [
    path.resolve('./proj1/assets/'),
    path.resolve('./proj2/assets/'),
  ],
},
```

Thus, the module import will be watched again.